# interpolate "dragged over" x values on a d3.js graph that the user draws

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js

The idea is to create a React.js app which allows the user to draw the Y values on a line graph. It works, but because the mouse is being moved faster than its position is being polled there are gaps as it is dragged.

[image]

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react';
import { select, line, curveMonotoneX, axisBottom, axisLeft, scaleLinear } from 'd3';

function App() {
    const svgRef = useRef(null);
    const [data, setData] = useState(Array.from({ length: 800 }, (_, i) => ({ x: i, y: 0 })));
    const [isDrawing, setIsDrawing] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        const svg = select(svgRef.current);
        const width = 800;
        const height = 400;

        const xScale = scaleLinear()
            .domain([0, data.length - 1])
            .range([0, width]);

        const yScale = scaleLinear()
            .domain([-1, 1])
            .range([height, 0]);

        const xAxis = axisBottom(xScale).ticks(10);
        const yAxis = axisLeft(yScale).ticks(5);

        svg.select('.x-axis').call(xAxis);
        svg.select('.y-axis').call(yAxis);

        const lineGenerator = line()
            .x((d) => xScale(d.x))
            .y((d) => yScale(d.y))
            .curve(curveMonotoneX);

        svg
            .select('.line')
            .datum(data)
            .attr('d', lineGenerator);
    }, [data]);

    const handleMouseUp = () => {
        setIsDrawing(false);
    };

    const handleMouseDown = (e) => {
        setIsDrawing(true);
        handleMouseMove(e);
    };

    const handleMouseMove = (e) => {
        if (!isDrawing) return;
        const { clientX, clientY } = e;
        const svg = svgRef.current;
        const { left, top, width, height } = svg.getBoundingClientRect();
        const offsetX = clientX - left;
        const offsetY = clientY - top;

        const xScale = scaleLinear()
            .domain([0, data.length - 1])
            .range([0, width]);

        const yScale = scaleLinear()
            .domain([-1, 1])
            .range([height, 0]);

        const x = Math.floor(xScale.invert(offsetX));
        const y = yScale.invert(offsetY);

        setData((prevData) => {
            const updatedData = [...prevData];
            const prevX = Math.max(x - 1, 0);
            const nextX = Math.min(x + 1, data.length - 1);
            const [prevY, nextY] = [updatedData[prevX].y, updatedData[nextX].y];

            for (let i = prevX + 1; i < nextX; i++) {
                const percent = (i - prevX) / (nextX - prevX);
                const interpolatedY = prevY + percent * (nextY - prevY);
                updatedData[i].y = interpolatedY;
            }

            updatedData[x].y = y;
            return updatedData;
        });
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <svg
                ref={svgRef}
                width={800}
                height={400}
                onMouseDown={handleMouseDown}
                onMouseUp={handleMouseUp}
                onMouseMove={handleMouseMove}
            >
                <g className="x-axis" transform="translate(0, 400)" />
                <g className="y-axis" />
                <path className="line" fill="none" stroke="blue" strokeWidth="2" d={line()(data)} />
            </svg>
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```